# XAMPP and phpMyAdmin time differences

Tags: mysql, xampp

I run XAMPP server, version 3.2.1 on my Windows PC.

I have a PHP code that shows me birthdays of users in my MySQL database. Sometimes I notice that it shows user that have birthdays the next day.
In phpMyAdmin, using `SELECT NOW();`, it shows my local time, but if I go to the Status tab, the time is 9 hours ahead.
If server and mysql run on my local computer, why are there different times in the same software (phpMyAdmin)?
Where can I check and change the timezone settings. I tried `SET time_zone = '-9:00';` or `SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';`, but nothing changed.

Advice would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Please don't give me "use Google" (I did that) or lecture me about formatting my post.

Comment: Change : date.timezone ="America/Los_Angeles" in your php.ini. You set time zone for MySQL but not for PHP.

Comment: Thank you. It was previously set to Europe/Berlin in php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for time zone :

MySQL : `SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'`

PHP : `date.timezone ="America/Los_Angeles"` in the php.ini

Time zone list here : http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php